# How to remove all cloned gui in roblox

Tags: for-loop, oop, lua, clone, roblox

I am creating a dance show game and I want to show the players name and their sequence in a list before each round. I am using clone which creates a new label for each player. My issue is that the cloned list is not getting removed after round 1 and the players name are duplicated. Here is my code

```
contList.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(Contestants)  ---Remote event in local script
for i=1,#Contestants do
        nameList  = script.Parent.List.plrsList.nameList:Clone()
        nameList.Parent = script.Parent.List.plrsList
        nameList.Name = Contestants[i].Name    
        nameList.nList.Text = Contestants[i].Name     --players name
        seqNo = script.Parent.List.sequence.seqNo:Clone()
        seqNo.Parent = script.Parent.List.sequence
        seqNo.Name =i                                 --sequence number
        seqNo.sequence.Text = i
        List = script.Parent.List
    end
    List.Visible = true
    wait(10)
    List.Visible = false
    for i=1,#Contestants do
        nameList:Remove()
        seqNo:Remove()
    end
end)
```

Comment: Instance:Remove() is deprecated   https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/Remove

Comment: I used destroy also still its not working @Piglet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you are cleaning things up, the `nameList` and `seqno` variables are only pointing at the last items you added to the list, it is not removing all of the items that you added.

There are a few different ways you could go about removing them, but the one that I will recommend will be to

1. Create an empty container like a Frame.
2. When creating a new TextLabel, put it as a child of that Frame.
3. When you are ready to clean up, just delete the Frame and that will remove all the children at once.

That would look like this :

```
contList.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(Contestants)  ---Remote event in local script
    -- find some UI elements
    local list = script.Parent.List
    local playersList = list.plrsList
    local playerNameList = playersList.nameList
    local sequence = list.sequence
    local sequenceNumber = sequence.seqNo

    -- 1. create an empty container for all players
    local container = Instance.new("Frame")
    container.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
    container.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)
    container.BackgroundTransparency = 1.0
    local layout = Instance.new("UIListLayout", container)
    layout.SortOrder = Enum.SortOrder.Name

    -- 1a. create a container for player names
    local playerContainer = container:Clone()
    playerContainer.Parent = playersList

    -- 1b. create a container for player numbers
    local sequenceContainer = container:Clone()
    sequenceContainer.Parent = sequence

    -- 2. create an entry for every player, and put them into their containers
    for i = 1, #Contestants, 1 do
        local nameList  = playerNameList:Clone()
        nameList.Name = Contestants[i].Name
        nameList.nList.Text = Contestants[i].Name
        nameList.Parent = playerContainer

        local seqNo = sequenceNumber:Clone()
        seqNo.Name = tostring(i)
        seqNo.sequence.Text = tostring(i)
        seqNo.Parent = sequenceContainer
    end

    -- momentarily show the list
    list.Visible = true
    wait(10)
    list.Visible = false

    -- 3. clean up by deleting the containers
    playerContainer:Destroy()
    sequenceContainer:Destroy()
end)
```